# Parenthesis on Filename for DOS

Tags: batch-file, character, dos

I'm writing a script to copy old files into a different folder.

I'm basing my script from this 
http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsDateTime.php

Everything runs smoothly until I check a file named

```
search_results_2014-04-16_142612(keywordsbroad-exact).xls
```

There seems to be an error with line 31 of code:

```
) ELSE (for /f %%a in ('"dir %attr% /-c "%file%"|findstr "^^[0-9]""') do call:jdate JD "%%a")
```

I believe the "(" and "")" are what are causing the problem. I tried adding ^( and %%( to the statement but I keep getting an error message..

The error message is .xls"|findstr "^[0-9]"" was unexpected at this time.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer double quotes are causing the problem. They are there to make it so you don't need to escape the `|`, but they are causing problems with your `%file%` because it is not quoted properly, leaving the `)` exposed, thus prematurely closing the IN() clause. The fix is to remove the outer quotes and escape the pipe. Also, the caret will now be properly quoted, so no need to escape it:

```
) ELSE (for /f %%a in ('dir %attr% /-c "%file%"^|findstr "^[0-9]"') do call :jdate JD "%%a")
```